# Do I need the standalone GRASS app if I have the GRASS Plugin and Processing toolbox enabled in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, standalone, qgis-grass-plugin

What processing abilities does the standalone GRASS GIS application have that aren't available in the QGIS GRASS plugin/toolbox?

I'm trying to understand whether you would need/want the standalone at all if using the GRASS plugin/processing modules in QGIS. I am using QGIS 3.4.3 on Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question but here you seem to be seeking a list of advantages rather than asking a focused question.

Comment: @ArchArchy, There are some GRASS functions that are not implemented as algorithms in QGIS. Before that, there are many configurations in the GRASS GIS functions that are not configurable in the QGIS algorithms. But much earlier than that, there is a very important base difference, GRASS GIS uses a topological vector model (see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/vectorintro.html#vector-model-and-topology). If the question is reopened, and consider this brief information enough to be an answer, do not hesitate to tell me to propose it as such, or feel free to quote it in your own answer.

Comment: @Gabriel thank you very much for your thoughtful answer. Perhaps someone else will also find it useful should my edits to the question be accepted!